# Render partial view code skeleton

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having difficulty rendering a partial view using the MVC3 razor engine.

When I select a `ToDate`, the jQuery UI datepicker will ajax POST by sending a JSON string as data.

ControllerView.cshtml:

```
to_date ({
    onSelect: function (selectedDate, inst) {
       // Some code here to construct JSON
       $.ajax ({
           // Appropriate attributes
           url: 'Controller',
           data: '{ FromDate: "' + data.FromDate + '", ToDate: "' + data.ToDate + '" }'
       });
    }
});

<div id="picker">
                <label for="FromDate">From: </label>
                <input type="text" id="FromDate" />
                <label for="ToDate">To: </label>
                <input type="text" id="ToDate" />
</div> <!-- END picker -->
<div id="Day">
    <!-- ****Where partial view should be rendered**** -->
</div>
```

This will be received by the controller(Controller.cs):

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Controller (DatePicker Dates)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save IList returned from query
        IList<Obj> JsonObj = Model.query(Dates);

        return PartialView("_PartialView", JsonObj);
    }
    return View();
 }
```

What should be my next steps?  I created a `_PartialView.cshtml` file, but I haven't been able to render the view.  Also, is my approach correct if I want the view to be rendered asynchronously?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: if for some reason Model.IsValid returns false, your action above will return a full view with the master page (if there is one). This is probably not what you want for an AJAX response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NathanTaylor.  I didn't quite know what to return so I just rendered a view for now. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a function to run on success of the ajax call:

```
to_date ({
    onSelect: function (selectedDate, inst) {
       // Some code here to construct JSON
       $.ajax ({
           // Appropriate attributes
           url: 'Controller',
           data: '{ FromDate: "' + data.FromDate + '", 
                    ToDate: "' + data.ToDate + '" }'
           success: function (result) {
               // when the AJAX succeeds replace the Day tag with the new view
               $('#Day').html(result);
           }
       });
    }
});
```

You should probably also handle when the request errors by assigning a function to `error:`. See the [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details on both `success` and `error`.

A bit of advice - I would highly recommend calling your action result something other than Controller.  I'm not sure if you will get the model state for this call since its an AJAX call so you might want to double check that part. I would also recommend you change your action result to take in both values by name.  Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RenderDatePartial(Date fromDate, Date toDate)
{
    var dates = new List<Date> { fromDate, toDate };

    // Save IList returned from query
    var jsonObj = Model.query(dates);

    return PartialView("_DatePartial", jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy workaround @link. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Do you know how I can deserialize the data?

Comment: Do you mean by deserialize the data on the client side? Why do you need to deserialize it?